# Performance Best Practice - Loading Paged Results via SQL, and also Loading the Total Results Found

Tags: c#, sql, performance

I have a general software practice question, and maybe a moderator could better phrase my title.

I'm loading out a list of paged results for a "Manage Users" page that has a bunch of filters.

In my system, there are 3000 users, and I want to show 25 per page, with a pagination control at the bottom.  No problem.  Here's the issue...

I want to show at the top of the page, that there say 2300 matches for my criteria, and so what I'm doing is running the same SQL query twice -- once with a limit of 25 records to build into objects (for pagination), and then again to get the unconstrained total count.

This seems non-performant. Is there a preferred way of doing this without having to run TWO SQL queries?

Comment: You should specify how do you implement pagination control. One solution could be caching all returned rows in a suitable data structure, so you can get the total count, and delegate the pagination to some code that accesses the cached rows to return the 25 rows bunches.

Comment: I think you will need two queries, but using `count` may be much better then retrieving entire resultset.

Comment: Unless your RDBMS supports also returning a 'total matches' parameter, there's two options - 1) Two queries, one which is a simple count, and the other which is the paginated results, and 2) one query, which gets _all_ results, and then counts/paginates them in the application.  For what it's worth, 2300 rows isn't usually a huge number, so you _may_ be able to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved a similar problem and went with the two query approach: the first query retrieved the current page of data (i.e., 25 rows), while the other one was used to retrieve the total count.

From your question it seems as though you are retrieving the entire dataset in your second query. As others have said, you will be much better off retrieving only the row count instead.

Grabbing only the row count in that second query should speed things up, but if you wanted to avoid running it each time you load some data, you could instead run it just once when the page is initially loaded, storing the result in the session or viewstate. This does of course mean that the count could become out of date if the number of rows changes, so you would need to evaluate the merits of accuracy against performance in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Don't run the same query but a `Count(*)` one. For example:

```
Select top 25 Name, Country, SomethingElse from SomeTable where Name like @name

Select Count(*) from SomeTable where Name like @name
```

This is easily achieved when using an ORM like NHibernate or Entity Framework. For plain-old sql, you'll need to create both queries.

Hope it helps.